# getting a called object is not a function or function pointer problem on line 34:13

Tags: c

So when I compile the code I get an error stating:

> called object is not a function pointer on line 34:13

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int calendar(int q,int m,int k,int j);

int main(){
    char days[8][100] = {"Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"};
    int q,m,k,j,year,day_num;
    printf("What day of the month is it? e.g. 31");
        scanf("%d", &q);
    printf("What month is it? e.g. January = 1, February = 2");
        scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("What year is it?");
        scanf("%d", &year);
    if(m == 1){
        m = 13;
        year--;
    }
    if(m == 2){
        m = 14;
        year--;
    }
    k = year%100;
    j = year/100;

    day_num = calendar(q,m,k,j);

    printf("The day for the selected date is %s", days[day_num]);
}
```

And the `calendar()` function is defined as:

```
int calendar(int q,int m,int k,int j){
    int day;

    day = (q+(13(m+1)/5)+k+(k/4)+(j/4)+(5*j)) % 7; // Problem is here

    return day;
}
```

Comment: As for your problem, I suggest you split the large expression into the smallest sub-expressions you can, using temporary variables for the results. When you do that I'm sure you will figure out the problem yourself.

Comment: Remember that multiplication must use `*` explicitly

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be "13(m+1)" on the line

```
day = (q+(13(m+1)/5)+k+(k/4)+(j/4)+(5*j)) % 7;
```

looks like you missed a ' * ' character(or something else) there. 13*(m+1) should solve your problem.